# Connecting QGIS to SQL server -- not showing sde

Tags: qgis, sql-server, spatial-database, sql-server-spatial

I have problem with seeing/making connection to spatial data on SQL Server with QGIS while I can normally see it (on the same SQL Server) with ArcMap.
I should use the same user and password for both programs.

QGis 3.22.5

ODBC: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 and 13 for SQL Server

---

ArcMap 10.8.1

Drivers: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client and SQL Server 2012 Native Client

Windows 10 Enterprise

[image: In ArcMap looks like this (and it should look the same in QGIS)]

In general, QGIS connects to this server but it shows some of the data that is not seen through ArcMap
[image: connection to wanted DB]

[image: some of the data]

when I mark just (to show) SDE it says *Unable to connect*
[image: marked SDE]

and if I do it with local admin again it shows some of the data (detecting), not the one I need and I cannot do anything with this data
[image: detecting data]

Do you have any suggestions what could be the problem?
I'm out of the ideas.

Comment: I doubt QGIS is going to show Enterprise Geodatabase feature datasets (which only exist as XML metadata). Versioned enterprise geodatabase feature classes are going to be problematic to access from non-geodatabase clients.